# How can I eliminate the gap in my Search Bar component when using React and CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I've just followed a tutorial from Youtube to create this Search Bar, but there exists a huge gap between the input and the form element itself.It's quirky, but I couldn't seem to fix the issue. I've cross checked the class name with its reference in CSS, and it seems that the search__input is the element that needs some work to eliminate the gap in the search bar.

[The Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xrh0.jpg)

I've came to a realization that it is a CSS issue somewhere in the code, and I've included the code below for easy checking. I hope an expert in React from here could help me solve this simple issue. Thank you in advance!

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faMagnifyingGlass } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import "./SearchBar.css"

const SearchBar = ({ posts, setSearchResults }) => {
    const handleSubmit = (e) => e.preventDefault()

    const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
        if (!e.target.value) return setSearchResults(posts)

        const resultsArray = posts.filter(post => post.title.includes(e.target.value) || post.body.includes(e.target.value))

        setSearchResults(resultsArray)
    }

    return (
        <header>
            <form className="searchbar" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    className="search__input"
                    type="text"
                    id="search"
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                />
                <button className="search__button">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
                </button>
            </form>
        </header>
    )
}
export default SearchBar
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input,
button {
  font: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

p {
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

article {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
}

header {
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchbar {
  width: 95%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.searchbar:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
}

.search__button,
.search__input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.search__input {
  /* padding: 1em; */
  width: 85%;
}

.search__button {
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  color: gray;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
}
```

Comment: hi, can you be more descriptive? what do you mean by " there exists a huge gap between the input and the form element itself". An input is a form element.. so I'm a bit confuse with that statement.

Comment: Hi Samson, as you'll see in the picture as "The Issue", there is a gap between the input (the element) and the form (the parent) itself. I just couldn't figure out how to close that gap using CSS code.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce; it works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/crL8ms7v/).

Comment: I think you may have to find a way to make the issue as clear as possible. Can't reproduce it too. it's working fine